# YouTube Live Streaming in Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have some questions regarding the YouTube Live Streaming API:

- Is there any support or code samples for javascript?
- Is it possible to embed the live streaming functionality into `Qt` applications by using the `Qt-WebKit` and javascript code, *e.g.* create broadcasts, bind to streams etc. via HTTP requests?

Comment: Any particularly reason you're still using the QtWebKit module now that it's no longer actively maintained?

Comment: @MrEricSir I am looking into possibilites of embedding Youtube functionality into a Qt GUI Application. And I assume, QtWebkit is the way to do it in Qt. What is your opinion? What would you suggest?

Comment: WebEngine/WebView would be the obvious choices if you're using a recent version of Qt.

Comment: Isn't the whole module called WebKit, as you include it by Qt+=webkit?

Comment: No, the entire QtWebKit module is no longer maintained. It's only available for legacy reasons.

Comment: Allright. And what about the live streaming funtionality? One can embed an iframe as @JAL mentioned in the comments below? (If that's it what downstreaming needs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a Live Event and Live broadcast is language-independent, just use YouTube's [Live Streaming HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/).  Read through the [Core Concepts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) and [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) guides.

Your flow might look something like this:

1. Authenticate the user.
2. Set up and schedule your Live Broadcast object.
3. Start your video encoder and create a Live Stream Object.
4. Bind your Live Stream to your Live Broadcast.
5. Test to verify your video is going through.
6. Set your Live Broadcast to Live.
7. At the conclusion of your event, set your Live Broadcast to Ended.

Note that setting up your encoder is on you.  Asking "How do I create an RTMP video encoder in JavaScript" (or qt) is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Creating, Binding is fine. But what about streaming itself? Am I going to be able to downstream and play content or even upstream a live event captured via camera&microphone?

Comment: @OnurA Downstream is easy, just use an embedded YouTube video IFrame.  Upstream is harder, you will have to write your own RTMP video encoder or integrate with an existing one.  I know that this is possible because YouTube does it in a browser with their [Stream Now](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard) feature.

Comment: This is not what the user asked. The user asked for JS examples.